# OptaPlanner benchmark: use in-memory input solution instead of inputSolutionFile

Tags: optaplanner

I'm trying to set up an OptaPlanner benchmark run.  Loading the problemBenchmarks from a file is proving to be problematic, as a lot of my classes are not serializable.  It will take a LOT of work to get that to function.

Is there a way to run a benchmark using the same unsolved solution that I use when I start my normal planner run, which is already constructed by my existing Java code? It would be trivial to start the benchmark if that would work somehow.

I find a partial solution in [OptaPlanner benchmarking without XML inputSolutionFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115141/optaplanner-benchmarking-without-xml-inputsolutionfile).

I was able to make that work, by coding an implementation of SolutionFileIO and using a static variable to pass along the unsolved solution that has already been created.

This works in a limited capacity.

Is there any way to set the unsolved solution directly on the PlannerBenchmarkFactory or the PlannerBenchmark, so that I don't have to use a static variable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just create a text file, for example `input1.txt` which is empty or only contains a 1 line identifier. Then implement a `SolutionFileIO`

```
public class MachineReassignmentFileIO implements SolutionFileIO<MachineReassignment> {

    public static final String FILE_EXTENSION = "txt";

    @Override
    public String getInputFileExtension() {
        return FILE_EXTENSION;
    }

    @Override
    public String getOutputFileExtension() {
        return FILE_EXTENSION;
    }

    @Override
    public MachineReassignment read(File inputSolutionFile) {
        // Ignore the inputSolutionFile or just read the id
        return ... // Create your solution manually
    }

    @Override
    public void write(MachineReassignment solution, File outputSolutionFile) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}
```

then just configure that

```
<problemBenchmarks>
  <solutionFileIOClass>org...MachineReassignmentFileIO</solutionFileIOClass>
  <inputSolutionFile>data/machinereassignment/import/input1.txt</inputSolutionFile>
  <problemStatisticType>BEST_SCORE</problemStatisticType>
</problemBenchmarks>
```

Comment: The problem with that approach (at least in my situation) is that MachineReassignmentFileIO is instantiated with the default no-args constructor. A instance of the class instantiated in that manner won't have access to the various constructs that are required to create the solution.

I'm currently using a static variable in MachineReassignmentFileIO to pass along what I need, and it works but is not great.  I guess I could use a thread local variable, but that is not much better than static.

Comment: Interesting point, feel free to open a jira for this. I guess we need to support alternatives to inputFileSolution elements